# errors in texmaker related to bibtex-working with a coauthor and using different distributions of latex

Tags: latex, dropbox, bibtex, miktex, texmaker

My coauthor and I work on a latex document in dropbox. It was working fine for me until I started receiving this error:

*This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file:myfilename.aux White space in argument*

I use Texmaker and my coauthor uses MikTex 2.9. So, I think he should have changed something that I cannot compile the file anymore.

I installed MikTex but I received "Sorry, but "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed." error. I tried several solutions discussed in other threads for this and none of them worked.

I appreciate your help with this problem.

Comment: How about removing the whitespace?

Comment: thanks! I am so uncomfortable with Latex that every time I receive an error I think it should be a major complex problem. The whole problem was a few caps mismatch and white space.

Comment: LaTeX is really a piece of cake once you read an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

@monica
In the configure texmaker, commands tab for bib{la}tex change the command to `%.bib`. The problem should resolve. For me it got resolved.

Hope this helps.